# python3 make (e=5): Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, cygwin, access-denied

When i run a make file on cygwin, there is Access is denied error.
There is a manifest file, input and output file passed as command line arguments to python script

> python3 C:/git/tool.py -m ./config/manifest.txt -i drv.bin -o drv_out.bin
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\bin\python3, python3 C:/git/tool.py -m ./config/manifest.txt -i drv.bin -o drv.bin, ...) failed.
>
> make (e=5): Access is denied.

Edit: make version

> make --version
>
> GNU Make 4.2.1 plus updates till 2017-June-04
>
> Built for Windows32

Comment: Can you run that command from the command.com shell?

Comment: Yes running python3 command on command line successful

Comment: from a POSIX shell?  Or from command.com?  GNU make on Windows is complicated because it can either be compiled "natively" for W32, or it can be compiled for cygwin (POSIX emulation), and it can be built to either use a POSIX shell (sh) to run commands or it can be built to run Windows shell (command.com) to run commands, etc.  Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Windows so I can't help, but it would be good to figure out first where you got your GNU make.  If you run `make --version` it should show some info about how it was built.

Comment: Please post all the details as stated in: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please post how do you invoke *make*, and if possible try to split the issue into smaller ones (that you could be able to solve yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping and commenting out.
I have installed cygwin long time back and the new make file is not compatible with the make version installed in cygwin.

I had to update the make binary to latest version to build.